# Confusion with front-page.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am slightly confused with front-page.php. I created a page "Home" from the backend of the wordpress and selected a custom template, let's say Food. I also have front-page.php. Now from settings page, I selected Home Page as my front page. But still I visit the website, it shows content from front-page.php.

When I already selected Home page as my front page, then it should show content from food Template not front-page.php. I am confused over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming *front-page.php* template, so the WordPress will not find it.

Then it should display the "Home" page with the custom template.

More information can be found on [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) site, which states:

> On the site front page, WordPress will always use the front-page.php
>   template file, if it exists. If front-page.php does not exist,
>   WordPress will determine which template file to use....

Comment: Yes, if I rename or delete it, then it is fine. This mean that front-page.php is always on front page regardless of template I select in the page from back end of wordpress.

Comment: Yes, it seems that when front-page.php is used, it uses a selected page for the main loop, but not much more.